# Google Analytics API Custom Segment w/ Date Range

Tags: c#, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I am using the Google Analytics API for performing queries against a specific site with a segment applied.

However, I have found that when I add an exclude filter that contains a date range (ex: Session Date is between 7/1/2016 and 7/31/2016 AND Source/Medium contains .....) the API will return a 400 error:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Segment *SEGMENTID* is not supported in the API. [400] Errors [ 
Message[
Segment *SEGMENTID* is not supported in the API.
] 
Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global] 
]
```

Has anyone else ran into this issue?  And if so, is there a resolution?  Thanks

JH

Comment: You should go ahead and include the full request you are making. If you are able you can call the [`segments.list`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/segments/list) and take the `"definition": "sessions::condition::dateOfSession<>2014-08-01_2014-08-31"`, field and use that in the `segmentId` field of the reporting API and see if you get a different error.

Comment: Sorry, I was already including the segmentId in the query.  If I remove the segment, the query runs without issue.  If I readd the segment and remove the date range from the segment the query runs without issue.  It appears to be specifically tied to having a date range within the segment.  I will try to copy the full request when I have access to the code again.

Comment: GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A63707326&start-date=2005-01-01&end-date=2016-07-28&metrics=ga%3Asessions&max-results=5&sort=-ga%3AuserAgeBracket&dimensions=ga%3AuserAgeBracket&segment=gaid%3A%3AgjEDXjxMRg2DFm7gUevjkw HTTP/1.1

Comment: Response:  {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"badRequest","message":"Segment gjEDXjxMRg2DFm7gUevjkw is not supported in the API."}],"code":400,"message":"Segment gjEDXjxMRg2DFm7gUevjkw is not supported in the API."}}

Comment: have you tried substituting the segment definition (call segments.list()) for the segment ID and see if you get any different results. Not all segments are supported in the API and some segments are pinned to a particular view. Also note that the maximum date range supported for `dateOfSession` is [30 days](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments#dateOfSession-conditions).

Comment: Also Analytics Reporting API V4 allows for [cohort](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced#cohorts) reports which might help you do what you need.

Comment: Yes, I tried querying with the segment definition with the same results.  I believe having the date range makes the Segment fall into that category of not being supported in the API.  I think a cohort report might possibly accommodate what I am needing to do.  Thanks!